# Directly access react router route on Wordpress hosted app

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router

I'm aware that this is a commonly asked question *in part*, however I believe that this situation is somewhat unique.

I'm running a React app in the form of a WP plugin. Here's how it works:

The plugin is set up to work on a specific page template (events.php). The React app is configured to work on this template as well. So, /events/ (The page set to use that template) is actually the home page of the app. This is important because a simple "catch-all" redirect solution does not solve my case, as the rest of the website needs to be accessible to the user.

Events are pulled in via Salesforce SOQL queries. The app shows a feed of events, and due to the nature of calendar events, the routes are obviously dynamic and ever changing. Here's my code for generating routes:

```
const generateEventRoute = route => {
  return (
    <Route key={route.Id} exact path={`/event/${route.Id}`}>
      <SingleEvent {...route} />
    </Route>
  )
}
```

And here's the rest of the Router system:

```
<Router basename="/events">
  <ScrollToTop />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <EventFeed />
    </Route>
    {eventList.map(event => generateEventRoute(event))}
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

The issue is the same as everyone else's, I can access routes just fine if starting from homepage, but can't access them when navigating to them directly (typing address in URL bar).

So far, I've tried one redirect rule, to no avail (I'm not at all versed in Apache configurations or redirects):

```
RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ /events [R=301,NC,L]
```

This resulted in a "TOO MANY REDIRECTS" error. I'm hoping that this might be solved with some magical redirect that I'm not smart enough to write, but I suspect it might be more complicated than that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In general with react, you don't want to rewrite to the specific url and allow apache to do the handling, you want to redirect to the main react app and allow it to do the redirecting. For example for one of our apps where index.html contains our react app (note if you are using create-react-app, you may need to change package.json to your react app root):

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Additionally, the webroot your app is hosted in must have the rule AllowOverride All or similar rule as appropriate. We place this file in the folder where the react app root is located, for example /public_html/myreactapp/.htaccess